# Cant Get UIView by Tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

[image]

I'm not sure why I cant get the UIView by tag from above screen.

- First pink bar is UIView with 55555 tag
- First yellow container is UIView with 555552 tag
- Label in first yellow container is 555553 tag

So my viewDidLoad as below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Address"];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#efeff4"]];

    UIView *addContainer1 = (UIView *)[self.view viewWithTag:555552];
    [addContainer1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#ffffff"]];

    UILabel *lblAddress1 = (UILabel *) [self.view viewWithTag:555553];
    [lblAddress1 setNumberOfLines:0];
    [lblAddress1 sizeToFit];
}
```

Below code working as expected. Changing whole view to grey color

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#efeff4"]];
```

Get label in first yellow also working as expected.

```
UILabel *lblAddress1 = (UILabel *) [self.view viewWithTag:555553];
[lblAddress1 setNumberOfLines:0];
[lblAddress1 sizeToFit];
```

But to get the UIView with 555552 tag (yellow container) is not working.

```
UIView *addContainer1 = (UIView *)[self.view viewWithTag:555552];
[addContainer1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#ffffff"]];
```

What I'm missing here?

Comment: Make sure that `addContainer1` is a subview of `self.view`, also check in Storyboard/Nib that tags not vanished.

Comment: make sure you have not assigned `555552` to some another UIView..

Comment: @Kampai yes fully checked. no issue with tag

Comment: @FahimParkar tried with different number also same

Comment: One more check - Put a break point (debug) on this line `addContainer1 ` and make sure you get not null object. And also in second line try set color with this `[UIColor whiteColor]`

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to create IBOutlets to these views and give them proper names? Seems you could avoid a lot of confusion. I had to count how many 5's were in the tags just to make sure you got them right.

Comment: @MikeTaverne i tried with IBOutlets too. still cant change the background color

Comment: can you make sample project for this and send link here? I will check from my end then...

Comment: I'm not sure why, after delete all the UIView and add again, now its working. Weird. I put break point as advice by @Kampai and get not null object. but anyway its working